# heightmap insertion unsuccessful with gazebo 7

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to use heightmap created by myself in gazebo, and I`ve followed tutorials like  [this one](https://www.vimeo.com/58409707) and  [this](https://github.com/MatthewVerbryke/gazebo_terrain). I use Ubuntu 16.04 and gazebo 7 as the second tutorial requires.

At first , I created a heightmap as the first tutorial instructed, and  I tested with my gazebo. It worked out, though occasionally the heightmap  wasn't loaded fully .  Only half of the terrain was loaded,  and the other half was flat.

But after a few hours I tried again. But no matter how I try , my gazebo always  crashes after I insert heightmap.
And the error msg is always the same:

```
gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::msgs::Response; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::msgs::Response*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

I've checked a [question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16319/gazebo-700-crash-on-heightmap-insertion/) asked by others before.But is there any better solution to this problem?
Updating gazebo to 8 may work, but it's not convenient and the tutorials insert heightmap with gazebo 7 successfully.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17984/heightmap-insertion-unsuccessful-with-gazebo-7/) by [bitpejoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4187/bitpejoy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2017-12-01**:
Can you try using gazebo 7.7? There are instructions in the question you linked to. I assume you are using a large image for the heightmap. Can you try using a smaller image?

**Comment by [bitpejoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4187/bitpejoy/) on 2017-12-01**:
My image is 129x129. Gazebo 7.9 works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Update gazebo to the 7.9.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install

get OSRF keys, and then `sudo apt upgrade`.

---

Originally posted by [bitpejoy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4187/bitpejoy/) with karma: 13 on 2017-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0